# Multiple task as one - Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, celery

I have a software which proceeds one picture and give me some results for that picture and a database which contains a lot of pictures.

I would like to build a distributed architecture in order to process these pictures on multiple servers in order to gain time.

I heard about Spark and searched about it, but I'm not sure that this solution is good for me. Nevertheless, I don't want to miss something.
Indeed, in all the example I found for Spark, **it's always dealing with tasks/jobs that can be split in smaller tasks/jobs.**
For example, a text can be split in mutliple smaller texts and so, the wordcount can be easy processed. 
However, when I use my software, I need to give a whole picture and not just parts of it.

So, **is it possible to give Spark a task which contains 10 pictures (for example), and then Spark splits it in smaller tasks (1 task = 1 picture) and sends each picture to a worker?**
And if it's possible, is this very efficient? I actually heard about Celery and I'm wondering if this kind of solution is better for my case.

Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends on what you mean by "lot of pictures" and how often you will get "lot of pictures" to process. If you have tens of thousands of pictures and you will get them frequently, then Spark will definitely a good solution.

From an architecture and requirements viewpoint I think either Spark or Storm will fit the bill. My main concern would be wether the overhead is justified. This talk for instance is about realtime image processing with Spark:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6qmEcGNgDo

You could so look at this quora thread:
https://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-developed-computer-vision-image-processing-algorithms-on-Twitter-Storm

Comment: So, with Spark, it's not necessary to have a task that can be split as many times as we want?
I mean, texts can be split in smaller texts but in my case, pictures can't.
Because of the fact that Spark is using map and reduce to do its job, I thought that such kind of job was necessary...
In my case for example, there won't be any key associated to my picture. That's why, the `groupBy` or `filter` things are not interesting for me...

Comment: The key could be the file name or path and the value is void. Then each task will process a file by taking its name or path and loading the binaries from the DB. That means, in this approach,  the binaries of the images do not need to be distributed through spark but only the names.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But I think I that I wasn't enough clear in my question. Sorry for that.

In fact, in every example of Spark I saw, the tasks can be split in smaller tasks. For example, in wordcount, we can split a text in smaller text, as many times as we want.
This comes from the fact that Spark uses MapReduce.
But in my case, I need every file not to be split because the software I use can only process one whole picture.

A text -> split -> multiple smaller texts.
A picture -> split -> nothing interesting.

So, only one worker can deal with one file in my case.
Is Spark still interesting?

Comment: If you really have tones of small size images, then I still see a value in using Spark to distribute the load, especially if the task is recurring. In your case, you take a huge list of file names, you split it, resulting into individual items, load the corresponding image in a distributed fashion, and process them.

Comment: Ok thank you, I better see.
One last question about how to implement. Regarding the 'structure' of Spark, I should put the software part in the map function and let the reduce function do nothing, right?